# Extract all occurrences of specific characters from strings

Tags: c#, .net, string, search

I have something like this in my code.

```
mystring.Split(new[]{"/","*"}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

however, what I actually want is to separate `mystring` into two arrays, one holding the separated items above, and the other array to hold the delimiters above in the order they appear in the string.

I could use `.IndexOf` to continue searching until I extract all of them, but somehow I think this will be redundant. Is there a way to do this in .NET? If possible I want to avoid LINQ.

Thanks.

Comment: Is there a reason you want to avoid LINQ?

Comment: I thought that the result of split is an array with the items in the order that they appear. Can u explain want u want further?

Comment: I want two results (if possible) from the split operation... or some other way to get the separated items and the delimiters as well. (which won't appear in the separated item array).

Comment: Some sample input with expected output would help clarify your question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like:

```
var separators = new char[] { '/', '*' };
var words = new List<string>();
var delimiters = new List<string>();
var idx = source.IndexOfAny(separators);
var prevIdx = 0;
while (idx > -1)
{
    if (idx - prevIdx > 0)
        words.Add(source.Substring(prevIdx, idx - prevIdx));

    prevIdx = idx + 1;
    delimiters.Add(source.Substring(idx, 1));
    idx = source.IndexOfAny(separators, idx + 1);
}
```

Comment: I actually had to add `words.Add(VT.Substring(prevIdx));` Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand the questioner correctly, he wants the actual separated items as well as the delimiters.

I think the following code will work:

```
        List<string> SeparatedItems = new List<string>();
        List<string> Delimiters = new List<string>();

        string sTestString = "mytest/string*isthis**and not/this";

        string sSeparatedItemString = String.Empty;
        foreach(char c in sTestString) {

            if(c == '/' || c == '*') {

                Delimiters.Add(c.ToString());
                if(sSeparatedItemString != String.Empty) {

                    SeparatedItems.Add(sSeparatedItemString);
                    sSeparatedItemString = String.Empty;  
                }
            }
            else {

                sSeparatedItemString += c.ToString();    
            }   

        }

        if(sSeparatedItemString != String.Empty) {

            SeparatedItems.Add(sSeparatedItemString);
        }
```

Comment: Great job. your approach is nice but will be quite slow for a large input.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var items = new List<string>();
var delimiters = new List<string>();
items.AddRange(Regex.Split(text, @"(?<=/)|(?=/)|(?<=\*)|(?=\*)"));

for (int i = 0; i < items.Count; )
{
    string item = items[i];
    if (item == "*" || item == "/")
    {
        delimiters.Add(item);
        items.RemoveAt(i);
    }
    else if (item == "")
    {
        items.RemoveAt(i);
    }
    else
    {
        i++;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could consider a Regex expression using named groups. Try a nested named group. The outer including capturing the separator and the inner capturing the content only.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're running in .NET 2.0, I'd say using `IndexOf` is one of the most straight forward ways to solve the problem:

```
public static int CountOccurences(string input, string pattern)
{
    int count = 0;
    int i = 0;

    while (i = input.IndexOf(pattern, i) != -1)
        count++;
    return count;
}
```

The solution Rob Smyth suggests would also work, but I find this the easiest and most understandable one.

Comment: Thanks for your effort. but I actually wasn't looking for the count.